# Angularjs ng include not working while using it to display navbar in index file

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement simple `ng-include` but it is not working. `Navbar` is not showing in the index page.

All the css files and html file directory is correct and linked well.
I have also used server for it using: `npm install -g http-server`.

here's my index.html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app='App'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Student Hub</title>
  <link href="../vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../vendor/css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
 <body ng-view>
  <ng-include src="'navbar.html'"></ng-include>

   <ng-include src="'footer.html'"></ng-include>



navbar.html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Instead of mentioning just file name, try it with relative or absolute path e.g. <ng-include src="'../vendor/html/navbar.html'"></ng-include>

Comment: @ShivPatne index, navbar and footer both are in same directory.